# downloaded video - AFHTTPRequestOperation vs. NSURLSessionDownloadTask

Tags: io, afnetworking-2

I try to update my existing download-model, so I have replaced my old code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloadRequest = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[downloadRequest setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:responseObject];
    [data writeToFile:video2Save.localFilePath atomically:YES];

    video2Save.downloadComplete = YES;
    [YEPersistentModelHelper saveData:_downloadVideos ToDiskWithIdentifier:persistentIdDownloadedVideos];

    NSLog(@"file downloading complete : %@", video2Save.localFilePath);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"file downloading error : %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
[downloadRequest start];*/
```

with the following:

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [_sessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:&progress destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4",video2Save.videoVersionId]];

} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
    video2Save.localFilePath  = [[filePath filePathURL] absoluteString];
    video2Save.downloadComplete = YES;
    [YEPersistentModelHelper saveData:_downloadVideos ToDiskWithIdentifier:persistentIdDownloadedVideos];


    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSDictionary *att = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:video2Save.localFilePath error:&err];
    NSLog(@"NSDictionary: %@", att);

}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

And it seems to work fine. The complete-block is executed & the file exists at the traced target.

The problem is, that I am no longer available to play the video! I use the MPMoviePlayerController which throws this useful error:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: { kind = 1; new = 2; old = 0; }
```

The only difference seems to be the file-permissions. The first one adds a "staff"-group & everyone is allowed to read while the second only grants access for "me". But even if I change it in the finder I am not able to play it...

Does anyone has an idea!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to save location file use path no absoluteString

video2Save.localFilePath  = [[filePath filePathURL] absoluteString];

don't call absoluteString even to play.. just use  the path 
like this for example to call the video

```
  NSURL *FilePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileToCheck]];
  [[myvideoCalss :[FilePathURL path]]
```

Comment: hey, I think that might have triggered this useful error ;)